# In Civ 4 is the Dutch Dike building the only building that adds production to non-river water tiles?

Tags: civilization-4

I'm looking for what would be the equivalent of Civ 2's offshore platform building, but it just looks like it's only the Dutch unique building of the dike which adds production to all water tiles. This seems strange to me since it seems like it would make the Dutch really overpowered in the late game

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no regular [coastal buildings](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Coastal_(Civ4)) that improve the production of water tiles.

However, the Wonder [Moai Statues](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Moai_Statues_(Civ4)) does have this effect, although this obviously can't be used in multiple cities.

Comment: Thanks, am I right that this makes the Dutch overpowered in late game play? Because from Civ 2 I know that once you get offshore platforms you turn your peninsula cities into trade + production powerhouses. And it seems poorly balanced to only give one civ this option.

Comment: @MCB I believe they are a top tier civ, also due to their leader having some of the best traits, Financial and Creative.